# Manipulating the item details of an outlook msg file in Windows Explorer using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have mashed up a VBA script from various web sources to save selected Outlook 2013 mailitems as *.msg files on the filesystem. This works well but I want to add things to the item properties shown in Windows Explorer (Windows 7).

A web search has thrown up confusing info as most seem to assume I want to change CustomProperties or BuiltinProperties but after a lot of time, it appears that what the DSOfile dll does for some other MS Office files is what I need.

In summary, I can select and run a macro to rename and save mail items to the file system as msg files. I am looking for a way to have those items on the file system show additional information when viewed in Windows Explorer. That is, additional columns showing some info beyond the default explorer view.

This information is only relevant within Windows Explorer to allow sorting etc. I cannot involve a separate database etc. I also need to do this within the VBA environment and do not have access to Visio etc.

As an example, Windows Explorer can show "Sender address" and "Sender name" columns. I want to populate these from within VBA for Outlook 2013 msg files.

Is this possible and how can it be done if so?

Comment: It looks like you need to customize the Windows Explorer view. The task is not related to Outlook at all.

Comment: The information comes from .msg files, not VBA. There is no way to get it done from VBA.

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that what I am trying to achieve is clear to you. Thanks for your contribution nonetheless.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the info comes from the msg files, but it is a property of the Windows Explorer which user specifies which column/properties to display, by right-clicking a column header and then selecting "More" to open the dialog allowing you to select many different properties to display.

Comment: @Dayo you can't "populate" these using VBA as far as I know, as Eugene notes, they are properties of the msg file which either exist or do not exist for each file. Can your problem statement be re-worded as: *How to manipulate the detail view of the Windows Explorer using VBA?"*

Comment: @DavidZemens I understand the question - where the data come from... Moreover, I know how to customize the Windows Explorer.

Comment: @eugene yes, I am just trying to clarify things. The OP is not very clear as to what is asked (specifically using the word "populate" when "configure" or "customize" is more appropriate) and your previous comment (there is no way to get it done) may be unclear depending what you meant by "it".

Comment: @DavidZemens I did use populate in a generic sense. I want to change the file properties. See: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/DSOFile.htm. I am not trying to change the view in Explorer but to change some specific document properties. Also, the example details I used are not significant. I just wanted to know how/if the properties could be amended. It is possible for some Office file types such as Word and Excel using DSOFile.dll but DSOFile does not appear to work for Outlook msg files. So, the question is specific to Outlook for this reason.

Comment: AFAIK the properties are read only

Comment: @DavidZemens That is a valid enough answer. I notice that when you right click on a Word/Excel file in Explorer, you get the custom tab under properties and that this is missing for msg files. Saw no reason for the terse answer and downvote I got from the first contributor though but nevermind! Was hoping I could edit a subset of msg file properties assuming that other are be read only. Other item is that if the msg file contains info such as sender (accessible in VBA as a mail item property), it should be possible to allow these to be displayed in Win Explorer even if they cannot be changed.

Comment: It is possible to display them in Explorer but I don't think is possible to do this from VBA. I looked around for a WinAPI function but didn't see anything promising...

Comment: @DavidZemens When I manually add more columns in Explorer, such as sender name and others you will expect to be available for msg files, I don't see anything. This will be just fine if possible. So, I have saved the files from Outlook and the only properties I can see in Explorer are the defaults: Date modified, Type and Size. Columns added for other fields turn up blank.

Comment: @Dayo, you need to develop Windows Explorer extension instead. Unfortunately VBA can't be used for this.

Comment: After reading all the comments I am still confused - do you want MSG specific properties to be displayed in Windows Explorer? Or do you simply want to read these MSG specific properties in your VBA code?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Apologies for the confusion. I just want them displayed in Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works for my purposes.

Not exactly the cleanest option but good enough as I can sort items in Explorer on specific columns.

```
Function setFileProps(filePath As String)
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
    objFile.Open(filePath)
    ' Use "Authors" column to hold Sender's Name
    objFile.SummaryProperties.Author = mItem.SenderName
    ' Use "Comments" column to hold Sender's email address 
    objFile.SummaryProperties.Comments = mItem.SenderEmailAddress
    objFile.save

    set objFile = Nothing

End Function
```

`mItem` is a mailItem from the main sub and this function is called from there after the mailitem is saved.

I have then set the target folder in Windows Explorer to show the Author and Comments columns.

Perhaps there are "cleaner" solutions

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution, though it also seems to require that `DSOFile` is installed.  I'd rather find a solution that works 'out of the box' without having to ask users to install additional dependencies.  Several years on, do you know of an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

These extra properties must be set on the OLE storage level used by the MSG file - `StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes` / `IPropertySetStorage::Create` / `IPropertySetStorage::WriteMultiple`

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes `olMsgWithSummary` format (similar to `olMsg` and `olMsgUnicode` in OOM) that will do what you need. The script below saves the currently selected Outlook message:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set oMsg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
set rMsg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(oMsg)
rMsg.SaveAs "c:\temp\ExtraProps.msg", 1035 '1035 is olMsgWithSummary
```